# C- Semaphore sem_getvalue not returning what I'm expecting?

Tags: c, semaphore

I've been trying to get myself more acquainted with semaphores and was wondering why this code isn't printing the value I expect.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    sem_t sem;
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 1);
    int value;
    sem_getvalue(&sem, &value);
    printf("%d\n",value);

    return 0;
}
```

It prints 0 for the value.  But from my understanding it should be getting the value I initialized the semaphore with which is 1?  I tried using a semaphore in some code with pthreads and I initialized the semaphore with a value of 1, but when I called the sem_getvalue function it was printing 32767.  Am I missing something here?  Thanks in advance.

Edit: sem_init and sem_getvalue both return -1

Edit:  Solved. It appears unnamed semaphores aren't implemented on Mac.

Comment: You're not checking the return value of sem_init nor sem_getvalue, that would be a good place to start to ensure some underlying error isn't happening.  That exact code, verbatim, prints 1 on my systems.

Comment: 0 just means that the call to get value was successful. With semaphores you shouldn't care about the value, just their state.

Comment: Hmm they both return -1 which means they failed.  What am I missing?  Is there some flag I need or something?

Comment: Well, I ran the same code and I get the `sem_getvalue() = 1`. So, there is nothing wrong with your code. I compiled it with `gcc del.c -lpthread` and then executed `./a.out`

Comment: I'm compiling as such: "gcc semtest.c -o semtest -lpthread"  I get that it equals 0.  Any idea why...?  So strange.

Comment: Weird apparently Mac only supports named semaphores..?

Answer (score 5):

I'm getting the output as expected. (i.e. 1)

try using linking with pthread library

```
gcc sema.c -lpthread
```

Comment: I've been doing that.  I think it's because Mac only supports named semaphores so like sem_open, sem_close, etc..

Answer (score 2):

```
Edit: Solved. It appears unnamed semaphores aren't implemented on Mac.
```

POSIX semaphore is considered as deprecated on Mac OSX. So, it doesn't work on it as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It should return 1, which is the value you init,
when compile should add `-pthread` as option, e.g. `gcc -pthread test.c`

If the code runs well, then both `sem_init()` and `sem_getvalue()` should return 0,
if they return -1 then there is some error, you should get error flag, and check man page on linux to see what error happend.

By the way, your code return 1 on my linux, which is correct.
The man page: `man sem_init` and `man sem_getvalue`. 
You should get error flag for sem_init(), then check `man sem_init` first, because the semaphore seems not properly created in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't really ans the question. Everything you said has already been discussed in the coomments.

Comment: It's because I'm using a Mac.  Unnamed semaphores are not implemented.

Comment: @brokenfoot -pthread provide better backward compatibility than -lpthread, if you don't understand it, check man gcc, or google for them.