# Semaphore value in function inside thread function inconsistent

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

I've been learning how to use `pthreads` and mutexes, and am confused about the output of the following C code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *TestThread(void *);
void TestFunc();

sem_t mutex;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t tid;
    sem_init(&mutex, 1, 0);
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, TestThread, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
}

void *TestThread(void *arg) {
    int val;
    sem_getvalue(&mutex, &val);
    printf("value of mutex in Thread function: %d\n", val);
    TestFunc();
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void TestFunc() {
    int val;
    sem_getvalue(&mutex, &val);
    printf("value of mutex in function in Thread function: %d\n", val);
}
```

I'm then compiling this like `g++ -lpthread mutexTest.c -o mutexTest` and running with `./mutexText`, which gives and output like

```
value of mutex in Thread function: 0
value of mutex in function in Thread function: 1754151134
```

Why is the mutex value changing in the function that I call within the thread? Did I lose the reference to the mutex somehow?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. The code looks OK to me offhand.

Comment: I also have not been able to reproduce, but just to eliminate one possible problem, try `sem_init(&mutex, 0, 0);`. If this changes the behavior, let us know.

Comment: what happens if you compile with a C compiler, like gcc instead of a C++ compiler?

Comment: @thb Making that change gives the same results

Comment: @bruceg Compiling with gcc produces the same results

Comment: +1 I notice no other potential problems. Interesting. Like you, I shall be glad to read the answer when it appears.

Comment: What operating system and version of gcc are you using?

Comment: @bruceg MacOS Mojave 10.14.2, gcc and g++ both say 
`Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1


Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)


Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0


Thread model: posix


InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

Comment: yeah... in MacOS `gcc` and `g++` are both aliases for the Mac compiler suite. I can't repro on my linux box. Hope someone else has a Mac.

Comment: What is `sem_getvalue()` returning in both cases?  If it's returning non-zero, what is `errno`? `sem_getvalue()` on a Mac seems to be troublesome.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655153/sem-getvalue-dysfunctionality-in-mac-os-x-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146950/c-semaphore-sem-getvalue-not-returning-what-im-expecting

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good idea. It returned -1 and `errno` is set to 78 in both the cases. It appears this means the function isn't set. Interesting.

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark When compiling with gcc or clang, you should always use the `-Wall` option.

Comment: For information, on my machine (Debian GNU/Linux 9, GCC 6.3, Pthreads 2.24), it returned 0 and `errno` is set to 0 in both the cases. Also for information, I am compiling with `-Wall` and, indeed, also with `-Wextra -Werror`.

Comment: If you actually need a mutex (not a counting semaphore), take a look at `pthread_mutex_create`, `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock`.

Comment: Running this on Linux works fine. @user3386109 is correct that they are deprecated and I should not be using them. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why your code fails. Unfortunately for our present purpose, your code succeeds on my machine.

Until someone else posts a proper answer, if you would like to try a few debugging ideas with me, at your option, we can try the following.

1.
Try the suggestion of @AndrewHenle: "What is `sem_getvalue()` returning in both cases? If it's returning non-zero, what is `errno`?"

For information, on my machine (Debian GNU/Linux 9, GCC 6.3, Pthreads 2.24), it returns zero and `errno` is also zero.

2.
Try changing

```
sem_t mutex;
```

to

```
volatile unsigned char buffer_before_mutex[0x1000];
sem_t mutex;
volatile unsigned char buffer_after_mutex[0x1000];
```

Reason: if something is overwriting your mutex on the stack, this might give it some empty space to overwrite instead of trashing the mutex. Even if this works (and I suspect that it won't), it will not be right; but it might afford a clue as to what is going wrong with your code.

3.
(My answer may have been overtaken by comments. I leave the answer here in case part of it proves useful nevertheless.)

Comment: What OP failed to notice is that `sem_init` and `sem_getvalue` are deprecated on MacOS. Compiling with `-Wall` would have made that abundantly clear.  The functions are just stubs that set `errno` and return.